# Javascript Incremental Looping

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a 3d grid with the Isomer JS library and need help figuring out the logic for an incremental loop.  Here is the Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqwrzL

Javascript:

```
function draw() {
    var iso = new Isomer(document.getElementById("grid"));

    var Shape = Isomer.Shape;
    var Point = Isomer.Point;
    var Path = Isomer.Path;
    var Color = Isomer.Color;
    var cube = Shape.Prism(Point.ORIGIN);
    var white = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0.4);

    makeGrid(8, 8, 0, new Color(100, 100, 100, 0.6));

    for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        iso.add(Shape.Prism(new Point(x, 0, 0), 1, 1, .5), white);
    }

    // GridMaker
    function makeGrid(xSize, ySize, zHeight, gridColor) {
        for (x = 0; x < xSize + 1; x++) {
            iso.add(new Path([
            new Point(x, 0, zHeight),
            new Point(x, xSize, zHeight),
            new Point(x, 0, zHeight)
            ]), gridColor);
        }
        for (y = 0; y < ySize + 1; y++) {
            iso.add(new Path([
            new Point(0, y, zHeight),
            new Point(ySize, y, zHeight),
            new Point(0, y, zHeight)
            ]), gridColor);
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet creates the solid blocks:

```
for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            iso.add(Shape.Prism(new Point(x, 0, 0), 1, 1, .5), white);
        }
```

`new Point()` values are ordered: x, y, z.  After every 8th iteration, I need the y value to increase by 1, which would start placing blocks on a new row.  This should also happen 8 times, effectively filling the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function draw() {
    var iso = new Isomer(document.getElementById("grid"));

    var Shape = Isomer.Shape;
    var Point = Isomer.Point;
    var Path = Isomer.Path;
    var Color = Isomer.Color;
    var cube = Shape.Prism(Point.ORIGIN);
    var white = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0.4);

    makeGrid(8, 8, 0, new Color(100, 100, 100, 0.6));

    for (x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
      for (y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        iso.add(Shape.Prism(new Point(x, y, 0), 1, 1, .5), white);
      }
    }

    // GridMaker
    function makeGrid(xSize, ySize, zHeight, gridColor) {
        for (x = 0; x < xSize + 1; x++) {
            iso.add(new Path([
            new Point(x, 0, zHeight),
            new Point(x, xSize, zHeight),
            new Point(x, 0, zHeight)
            ]), gridColor);
        }
        for (y = 0; y < ySize + 1; y++) {
            iso.add(new Path([
            new Point(0, y, zHeight),
            new Point(ySize, y, zHeight),
            new Point(0, y, zHeight)
            ]), gridColor);
        }
    }
}
```